# calling multiple query results inside vba function

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have been working for `MS Access` payroll.. How can you call a query that's already made in Access inside a VBA function?

```
Public Function InsertAndUpdate()
    //i want my queries here for conditioning
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("Your_Query_Name")
```